# What run level activates on reboot, shutdown, and start?

Tags: 14.04, runlevel

I'm trying to get a better understanding of run levels and things.

I have created two scripts in /etc/ one is called `cinit` and the other `cdinit`.  The scripts stand for "custom initialize" and "custom de-initialize" so I can run some custom commands.  The `cinit` file only will run with a `start` parameter and the `ddinit` will only run with a stop parameter (Checked by a switch case in the file).

I am going to make `symlinks` to these scripts:

> S prefix link to `cinit` in rc2,rc3,rc4,rc5
>
> K prefix link to `cdinit` in rc0,rc6

1. My understanding is that: If I start the server from an off state,
   it enters run levels 2, 3, 4, or 5.
2. If I `sudo reboot` then the server will first enter run level 6, and then re-enter run levels 2, 3, 4, or 5.
3. If I shutdown the server then it will enter run level 0.

Is this how the rc folder scripts are run?